# Monitor bandwidth, memory, cpu per domain on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the best solution in python, to monitor CPU, memory, and bandwidth usage **per domain**?

This solution has to also work on multiple instances.

Comment: This is NOT off topic. The person is trying to find a way to monitor a server with CODE. Specifically Python. In case you haven't heard, Python is a programming language. And there are not many tools for python for monitoring EC2. 

For the poster. Try the Boto library. It allows you to do quite a bit with AWS using Python, including monitoring.

Comment: I agree with BillR. I suggest you check out this article http://www.elastician.com/2009/05/using-ec2-cloudwatch-in-boto.html and then look at http://supervisord.org/ and since cloud watch doesn't give you data in the same way as you might expect look at https://code.google.com/p/psutil/. I've used a combination of all the above plus Pusher to build a very nice control and monitoring system.

Comment: I provided a full program for memory monitoring in AWS, written in Python, using CloudWatch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556795/simple-aws-cloudwatch-program-for-memory-and-disk-usage-monitoring

Answer (score 1):

Have you checkout out [Amazon CloudWatch](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/cloudwatch_tut.html)?

> Amazon CloudWatch enables you to monitor your AWS resources in
>   real-time, including **Amazon EC2 instances**, Amazon EBS volumes, Elastic
>   Load Balancers, and Amazon RDS DB instances. **Metrics such as CPU
>   utilization, latency, and request counts are provided automatically
>   for these AWS resources. You can also supply your own custom
>   application and system metrics, such as memory usage, transaction
>   volumes, or error rates**, and Amazon CloudWatch will monitor these too.
>   With Amazon CloudWatch, you can access up-to-the-minute statistics,
>   view graphs, and set alarms for your metric data. Amazon CloudWatch
>   functionality is accessible via API, command-line tools, the AWS SDK,
>   and the AWS Management Console.

You could then use [Amazon Python boto library to access CloudWatch statistics](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/cloudwatch_tut.html).

Answer (score 1):

CPU can be monitored by CloudWatch using the built-in metrics. For memory you can use custom metrics with the AWS command line tools or write powershell/ruby scripts with the official AWS SDK.

You can monitor anything that's easily quantifiable using the AWS SDK. To monitor bandwidth usage per domain I'd recommend something like ntop.

Comment: `For memory you can use custom metrics with the AWS command line tools` can you give some more details about this? thanks